# Kendo-Knockout: How to filter and sort a remote data source?

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, odata, knockout-kendo

I am trying to get `KendoGrid` and `Knockout JS` working together. So far, so good.. except that I don't know how to get filtering and sorting working with a remote data source (I don't want to load all of the data on the client side before being able to sort and filter it.). Here's what I have so far:

**MARKUP**

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="Grid" data-bind="kendoGrid: Records"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var PageVM = function (model) {
    model = model || {};
    var self = this;
    self.Id = ko.observable(model.Id || 0);
    self.Title = ko.observable(model.Title || '');
    self.Slug = ko.observable(model.Slug || '');
    self.MetaKeywords = ko.observable(model.MetaKeywords || '');
    self.MetaDescription = ko.observable(model.MetaDescription || '');
    self.IsEnabled = ko.observable(model.IsEnabled || false);
    self.BodyContent = ko.observable(model.BodyContent || '');
    self.CssClass = ko.observable(model.CssClass || '');
    self.CultureCode = ko.observable(model.CultureCode || '');
}

var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Records = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.Refresh = function () {
        OData.read({
            requestUri: "/odata/cms/Pages"
        },
        function (data, response) {
            viewModel.Records([]);
            $.each(data.results, function () {
                var pageVM = new PageVM(this);
                viewModel.Records.push(pageVM);
            });
        },
        function (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        });
    };

    self.Edit = function () {
        alert("test");
    };

    ko.bindingHandlers.kendoGrid.options = {
        pageable: {
            refresh: true
        },
        scrollable: false,
        columns: [{
            field: "Title",
            title: "Title"
        }, {
            field: "Slug",
            title: "Slug"
        },{
            field: "IsEnabled",
            title: "IsEnabled"
        },{
            field: "Id",
            title: " ",
            template: '<a onclick="edit()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a> <a href="Delete/#=Id#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>'
        }]
    };
};

var viewModel;

$(document).ready(function () {
    viewModel = new ViewModel();
    viewModel.Refresh();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});

function edit() {
    alert("test");
}
```

As you can see, I am using OData. As for the `kendoGrid` knockout binding, that's coming from here:
http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Grid.html

I guess what I need to do is probably get the filters and sorts from the KendoGrid itself first and then manually append that to an odata query string. I would also manually have to tell Kendo the total number of pages so it knows how many page numbers to display in the grid.

So, I think I know what needs to be done, but I don't know where to start (how do I get/set such data with the KendoGrid, for example?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours trying to make this work, I ended up deciding on a simpler solution: use the `KendoGrid` with the `OData` source directly and then only use `Knockout` for creating and editing single entries (it doesn't need to be aware of all entries in the grid).

This also took a while to figure out though.. the following link was a good start:
http://blogs.telerik.com/kendoui/posts/12-10-25/using_kendo_ui_with_mvc4_webapi_odata_and_ef

However, it didn't give me all the answers I needed. For example, I needed to figure out that ASP.NET Web API uses the property `value` for the data and `odata.count` for the total number of records. Here is my final implementation (minus the knockout stuff):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Grid").kendoGrid({
        data: null,
        dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/odata/cms/Pages",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: function (data) {
                    return data.value;
                },
                total: function (data) {
                    return data["odata.count"];
                }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
        },
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: {
            refresh: true
        },
        scrollable: false,
        columns: [{
            field: "Title",
            title: "Title"
        }, {
            field: "Slug",
            title: "Slug"
        },{
            field: "IsEnabled",
            title: "Is Enabled"
        },{
            field: "Id",
            title: " ",
            template: '<a onclick="editRecord(#=Id#)" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Edit</a> <a onclick="deleteRecord(#=Id#)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>'
        }]
    });
});
```